# Parse input when dealing with file names

Tags: python, shlex

How can I parse the input when it is a list of paths?

```
file_in = input("Insert paths: ")  # foo.jpg "C:\Program Files\bar.jpg"
print(file_in)  # foo.jpg "C:\Program Files\bar.jpg"
```

I'm looking for a clean way to get the input `foo.jpg "C:\Program Files\bar.jpg"` in a list `['foo.jpg', 'C:\Program Files\bar.jpg']` (note the quotes in the second path because of the space in `Program Files`).

Is there something like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) but for `input()`s?
What is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
import shlex

file_in = input("Insert paths: ")  # foo.jpg "C:\Program Files\bar.jpg"
print(shlex.split(file_in))  # foo.jpg "C:\Program Files\bar.jpg"
```

Output:

```
['foo.jpg', 'C:\\Program Files\\bar.jpg']
```